# How to implement a simple PACT-JVM solution on existing Scala code-base

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

We are trying to implement a Hybrid approach for PACT-provider for Scala.
We're looking for a simple example of Pact-JVM-provider side implementation using PACT-JVM (Java variant)
We've the project code-base in Scala, but would like to try Pact JVM (Java variant) on top of it for Pact testing (Provider-side). I tried searching the sample for this hybrid approach but couldn't find one, so asking around for help.

Does anyone has a sample git repo of simple implementation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find exact matching solution, fulfilling the requirement of Scala code base & PACT tests written in JAVA.
Whereas, below referred two solutions goes somewhat closer, to what we're looking for:

1. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/specs2
2. https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/provider/scalatest

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]